# A Simpler Solution for a special case of the Set Cover problem

Tags: set-cover, polygon

We decomposed a simple polygon into many small regions. Then we estimated a visibility polygon of a point by a subset of the small regions. Now I need the minimum set of visibility polygons that can cover all the small regions, the whole polygon. This can be seen as an instance of the Set Cover problem. However, I need an easier approach. As we deal with visibility polygons inside a simple polygon there must be an easier way than a general instance of the Set Cover problem.

Comment: for reference, the problem is NP-hard, but it looks like there is a polytime constant-factor approximation algorithm, and maybe a PTAS [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem].  If for some reason you need to do it via set cover, properly formulated, it may be a special case of geometric set cover, which is somewhat easier than general set cover [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem].

Comment: The wikipedia page on geometric set cover is out of date. It does not refer to the large amount of progress made in the last decade or so.

Comment: Thank you. A PTAS algorithm for the general Art Gallery problem cannot be provided and constant approximation factor provided by Gosh in arXiv is not correct. As far as I know, a constant factor approximation algorithm for the Art Gallery problem is still open.

Comment: About the geometric set cover. I am not sure if my estimated visibility polygons can be counted as objects in the geometric set cover. Although these visibility polygons has shared a lot of small regions and perhaps we can count on the frequency of the small regions in the related set cover instance, i am not sure if there is any paper that counts on the visibility polygons as objects.

Comment: Please inform me about the last results on geometric set cover.

Comment: See following papers and references. https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973099.125, https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0835, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.13420.pdf, http://chekuri.cs.illinois.edu/papers/fast-geometric-lp.pdf. These are only a few that came to mind but there are several others which are hopefully covered in the references.

Comment: I also want to say that the art gallery problem may not be part of the progress - thought that it is worth pointing out the other cases since the wikepedia page is not updated.